# Why is `export * as Name from './module'` not a thing in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

Many of the import forms in JavaScript and TypeScript have export parallels, to allow for easy re-exporting of values and types. E.g.

```
export { A, B } from './module'
```

or

```
export { default as Name } from './module'
```

Ohers don't, for reasons that make sense to me. E.g.

```
export Name from './module'
```

wouldn't make sense, as we're not specifying which name we want to re-export `Name` under.

But why does this not work:

```
export * as Name from './module'
```

Isn't it clear that we're exporting all named exports from `'./module'` under the `Name` name? To me it seems obvious that our intention here is to group all the exports from the file into an object which we then export just like another named export, similarly to how this is ok

```
import * as Name from './module'
```

because it's clear that we're importing all exports under the `Name` name

Comment: I can't think of a reason why that wouldn't work to be honest. Not sure what the intention of the spec authors was, or if that was just omitted without any purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be used because it hasn't appeared in the ES Module specification. It is currently, together with the `export name from 'mod'` syntax, a stage 1 proposal.

See:

- [`export * as name from 'mod'` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from)
- [`export name from 'mod'` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-default-from)

You can use these features now by using [Babel](https://babeljs.io), a JavaScript transpiler.